# How do I properly extract class tags with html?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to extract html data with BeautifulSoup, but I can't seem to properly take the 'class' tag from the html and into my code. Here's what I tried:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = "https://allauthor.com/quotes/"

uClient = uReq(url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "quote-list"})
print(containers)
```

Here I'm expecting to get the list of quotes from the website, but for some reason I get nothing when I run the code. How do I get the list of quotes, or at least one quote in plain text on my console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see is loaded from external URL via JavaScript. To load it manually you can use next example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://allauthor.com/getQuotesDirectory.php"

data = {
    "draw": "1",
    "columns[0][data]": "0",
    "columns[0][name]": "",
    "columns[0][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[0][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[0][search][value]": "",
    "columns[0][search][regex]": "false",
    "start": "0",
    "length": "50",
    "search[value]": "",
    "search[regex]": "false",
    "orderby": "usersView desc",
    "status": "Y",
    "category": "",
    "author": "",
}

data = requests.post(url, data=data).json()

for i, row in enumerate(data["aaData"], 1):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(row[0], "html.parser")
    print("{:<3} {}".format(i, " ".join(soup.div.text.split())))
```

Prints:

```
1   May God shower his choicest blessings on you. wishing you happiness, good health and a great year ahead.Birthday 9,184
2   A mind all logic is like a knife all blade. It makes the hand bleed that uses it. Rabindranath TagoreLogic 6,480
3   Reality of life When you give importance to people they think that you are always free But They dont understand that you make yourself available for them every time.New Collection 6,164
4   Xcuse me, I found something under my shoes. Oh its your attitude.Attitude 6,024

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Is there a way of getting this without loading an external url?

Comment: @BluBalloon Another option is using `selenium` or similar module.

Comment: I spent some time trying to understand the data, but there are a few things I still don't understand; if you don't mind, can you explain to me what "draw", "status" and "oderby" do?

Comment: @BluBalloon That's the data that webpage sends to server (you can see the request in Chrome (or Firefox) Developer Tools -> Network Tab when you reload the page). I don't know the meaning of these parameters, its how the web page was implemented.